# Unable to configure SMTP authentication support module

Tags: 7, emails

In Drupal v7.36 & 7.37, after installed and enabled [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module, I still can't find the menu function under configuration/system to config this module for all related email setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache and go to the following path: admin/config/system/smtp or Home » Administration » Configuration » System » SMTP Authentication Support

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache either from the terminal using:

> drush cc all

or from the UI, going to

> Admin -> Configuration -> Development -> Performance

Clear the cache once and you would be able to see the Menu under configuration/system